# How to filter entity_autocomplete results by content type and a field

Tags: entities, forms, 9, plugins

I am trying to implement an entity autocomplete field in a form where the autocomplete entities are filtered by content type and a certain field of that content type.

I know I can filter the autocomplete by using `target_bundles` in the `#selection_settings`

```
'#selection_handler' => 'default',
'#selection_settings' => [
  'target_bundles' => ['my_content_type'],
]
```

But I'm still lost on how to further filter by a field in this content type.  From what I found, I can add `'filter' => ['my_field_name' => 'my_field_value'],` to the `#selection_settings`.  But then I would have to use a custom `#selection_handler`.

I found this example online about implementing a selection handler plugin.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\test_module_name\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection;

use Drupal\node\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\NodeSelection;

/**
 * Provides specific access control for the node entity type.
 *
 * @EntityReferenceSelection(
 *   id = "default:node_by_field",
 *   label = @Translation("Node by field selection"),
 *   entity_types = {"node"},
 *   group = "default",
 *   weight = 3
 * )
 */
class NodeByFieldSelection extends NodeSelection {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function buildEntityQuery($match = NULL, $match_operator = 'CONTAINS') {
    $query = parent::buildEntityQuery($match, $match_operator);
    $handler_settings = $this->configuration['handler_settings'];
    if (!isset($handler_settings['filter'])) {
      return $query;
    }
    $filter_settings = $handler_settings['filter'];
    foreach ($filter_settings as $field_name => $value) {
      $query->condition($field_name, $value, '=');
    }
    return $query;
  }

}
```

I believe in this example they are using a selection handler called `default:node_by_field`.  I'm completely new to plugins but am familiar with modules.  I feel I'm very close.  Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using Views module? You can create views of type `Entity Reference` and then select this (pre-filtered) view as source for your entity reference field.

Comment: I need this form to be generated fully programmatically and views didn't seem to fit my needs in that regard.  So I'd prefer to solve this using form render elements